# Magento2 Elastic search curl request for Fetch category and layered navigation data

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I have implement Elastic search for my magento2 project and it working fine.
But want to know how Elastic Search module Post our query to Elastic Database and retrieve data and need to know how Elastic module Query build for fetch data from Elastic.

Let me know if anyone have idea.

Comment: Did you get it how elastic search applied query ?